# Android networking with volley and okhttp3 issues with outdated information

Tags: android, android-volley, android-networking, okhttp

From reading various online blogs/tutorials, *volley + okhttp + gson* seems like the way to go. But I cannot get a simple networking project up and running because of outdated/conflicting information online. Can someone help me sort through it?

[This outdated article](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-networking-i-okhttp-volley-and-gson-72004efff196?gi=36875047a595) says that in order to use okhttp with volley, I need to use a custom implementation of httpstack for okhttp. So I found and use this [updated okhttpstack version for okhttp3](https://gist.github.com/bryanstern/4e8f1cb5a8e14c202750) since okhttp3 is latest now.

But when I load it into my project, the following errors occur:

**1) Incompatible type in okhttp3stack**

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine;

// ...

@Override
public HttpResponse performRequest(com.android.volley.Request<?> request, Map<String, String> additionalHeaders)
        throws IOException, AuthFailureError {

    // ...

    BasicHttpResponse response = new BasicHttpResponse(responseStatus);
    response.setEntity(entityFromOkHttpResponse(okHttpResponse));

    // ...

    return response;
}

private static HttpEntity entityFromOkHttpResponse(Response r) throws IOException {
    BasicHttpEntity entity = new BasicHttpEntity();
    // ...
    return entity;
}
```

And Android Studio complains about the errors:

```
Incompatible types: 
    Required: HttpResponse
    Found: BasicHttpResponse

Incompatible types:
    Required: HttpEntity
    Found: BasicHttpEntity
```

Which is it? Should I be changing the function definition to return `BasicHttpResponse`, or change the variable to return `HttpResponse`? Similarly, what should I do for the http entity error?

**2) It's using the legacy apache http library.**

From documentation, I'm told that *HttpURLConnection* is the one I should be using. When I run this with the outdated apache http library, I see this:

```
Error:(30, 23) error: package org.apache.http does not exist
Error:(31, 23) error: package org.apache.http does not exist
Error:(32, 23) error: package org.apache.http does not exist
Error:(33, 23) error: package org.apache.http does not exist
Error:(34, 30) error: package org.apache.http.entity does not exist
Error:(35, 31) error: package org.apache.http.message does not exist
Error:(36, 31) error: package org.apache.http.message does not exist
Error:(37, 31) error: package org.apache.http.message does not exist
Error:(62, 12) error: cannot find symbol class HttpResponse
Error:(105, 20) error: cannot find symbol class HttpEntity
Error:(159, 20) error: cannot find symbol class ProtocolVersion
Error:(90, 9) error: cannot find symbol class StatusLine
Error:(90, 41) error: cannot find symbol class BasicStatusLine
Error:(91, 9) error: cannot find symbol class BasicHttpResponse
Error:(91, 42) error: cannot find symbol class BasicHttpResponse
Error:(98, 40) error: cannot find symbol class BasicHeader
Error:(106, 9) error: cannot find symbol class BasicHttpEntity
Error:(106, 38) error: cannot find symbol class BasicHttpEntity
Error:(162, 28) error: cannot find symbol class ProtocolVersion
Error:(164, 28) error: cannot find symbol class ProtocolVersion
Error:(166, 28) error: cannot find symbol class ProtocolVersion
Error:(168, 28) error: cannot find symbol class ProtocolVersion
```

Various blogs say to just add the apache http library to the gradle file, but I don't want to do this because it's going to be deprecated. Since HttpURLConnection is the current iteration, I want to use that. How would I update this to use *HttpURLConnection*?

**3) There is a comment somewhere saying that the okhttp3stack won't work for HTTPS.** I don't quite understand what this means. If it's true, how would I support HTTPS then?

Basically, as a total android noob, I'm totally confused on how to do simple networking in android. My ultimate goal is to make a GET/POST/PUT request to an external API.

Can someone help in getting this to work properly, or show a fully working example using updated/modern networking libraries?

Comment: Volley and OkHttp overlap strongly. Choose one or the other. IMHO, using both is pointless. My personal recommendation is OkHttp.

Comment: "show a fully working example using updated/modern networking libraries?" -- this would be covered in any decent book on Android app development. Here are sample projects, implementing the same basic app, using [OkHttp](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Internet/OkHttp3) and [Volley](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/HTTP/Volley), as well as [Retrofit](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/HTTP/Retrofit2) and [Retrofit + Picasso](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/HTTP/Picasso).

Comment: @CommonsWare Why does that article say that using okhttp and volley is a popular choice? Is it leveraging benefits from both volley and okhttp? Like volley has support for loading images, but okhttp doesn't. Volley also has the requestQueue. By mixing the two, is the author trying to get the best of both worlds? The article was written in 2015, so things may have changed, but I wouldn't know.

Comment: "Like volley has support for loading images, but okhttp doesn't" -- there are plenty of dedicated image-loading libraries that are much better than Volley (Glide, Picasso, etc.). "Volley also has the requestQueue" -- OkHttp has `enqueue()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there an example for okhttp3 with picasso?

Comment: I do not think that I wrote that combination, sorry.